# How to keep "--disable-web-security" for some testcases and for others skip "--disable-web-security"

Tags: java, playwright

```
   @BeforeMethod
  public void setUpPlaywright(ITestResult testData) {
    String[] chromiumArgs = {
      "--disable-web-security",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors", // Additional options if needed
      "--PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL"
    };
```

As for the above code, I'm passing chrome arguments to initialize playwright web driver.
Unfortunately, there is a one test case where it's mandatory to remove  `"--disable-web-security"` from the argument list.
Because with the original argument set, web page is not loading.
If I remove  `"--disable-web-security"` then the web page is successfully loading.

So how to keep  `"--disable-web-security"`, for some test cases and for some remove  `"--disable-web-security"` at the driver setup?